# Can a Muslim woman marry a disabled Muslim man?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam, nikah

I am a disabled muslim man thinking of proposing to someone.

What do Muslim women think about marrying a disabled Muslim man? Am I considered a burden? ***What does hadith say about disabled man marrying?***

Comment: First part of your question is a bit opinionated.

Answer (score 2):

According to Hadith, the Messenger (p.b.u.h) admonishes us to [respect the disabled](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1837a) and to be [helpful](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2297).

There is nothing said about disabled grooms or brides. If a woman freely decides to be your wife, she will do it for your qualities and she will know that she will have to live with the obstacles linked to your disability, and maybe she likes to be helpful.